# batch script to replace text in multiple files

Tags: batch-file, powershell

I have a multiple xml file (extension '.xml') where i need to find and replace text.
i have text in following pattern.

```
<Music href="6000111.genre" title="AAA">
<Music format="ditamap" href="000760.rock" title="222"/>
<Music format="ditamap" href="000756.rock" title="333"/>
</Music>
```

href is currently 6 digit number with extension 'rock'.

I need to add previx 'Z' infront of href with extension .rock. that is `href="000760.rock` --> `href="Z000760.rock`

I should be getting the following as result:

`<Music href="6000111.genre" title="AAA">
    <Music format="ditamap" href="X000760.rock" title="222"/>
    <Music format="ditamap" href="X000756.rock" title="333"/>
</Music>`
Will really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should show some effort. What have you tried?

Here's one solution:

```
#Get XML files
Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\myXMLsource" -Filter "*.xml" | ForEach-Object {
    #Read all text in file
    (Get-Content $_.FullName) |
    #Foreach line, Add Z prefix in href value.
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '(?<=href=")(\d{6})(?=\.rock")', 'Z$1' } |
    #Save text
    Set-Content $_.FullName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.xml) do (
type "%%a" | repl "([0-9]*\.rock)" "Z$1" >"%%a.tmp"
move /y "%%a.tmp" "%%a"
)
```